# Compare two bits of an integer python

Tags: python, bit

I'm trying to compare two consecutive bits of an integer n and operate with than, like if there are equal I can do some thing and else do other thing. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please explain it with an example. What bits do you want to compare?

Comment: Considering that the least significant bit is the bit `0`, you can get the `n`-th bit of an integer `i` like this: `(i >>> n) & 1`.

Comment: Thanks, `(i>>>n)&1` worked.

Comment: I think both prior comments meant `(i >> n) & 1` -- double-arrow, not triple. Triple-arrow is invalid syntax in Python.